# socket.io ack with binary data in object property

Tags: socket.io

I have a node.js sever using socket.io. I'm returning an object that has an `id` value in it. This value is binary. Currently I'm letting socket.io deal with this because it states that it can handle binary values. The server log for a request looks like this:

```
socket.io:socket sending ack [null,[{"id":{"type":"Buffer","data":[187,147,6,248,235,251,17,230,158,219,131,162,166,89,203,237]},"name":"Test project"}]] +7ms
socket.io:client writing packet {"id":0,"type":6,"data":[null,[{"id":{"type":"Buffer","data":[187,147,6,248,235,251,17,230,158,219,131,162,166,89,203,237]},"name":"Test project"}]],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
socket.io-parser encoding packet {"id":0,"type":6,"data":[null,[{"id":{"type":"Buffer","data":[187,147,6,248,235,251,17,230,158,219,131,162,166,89,203,237]},"name":"Test project"}]],"nsp":"/"} +8ms
socket.io-parser encoded {"id":0,"type":6,"data":[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]],"nsp":"/","attachments":1} as 61-0[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]] +0ms
engine:socket sending packet "message" (61-0[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]]) +8ms
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
engine:ws writing "461-0[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]]" +0ms
engine:socket sending packet "message" (�������ۃ��Y��) +0ms
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +1ms
engine:ws writing "�������ۃ��Y��" +0ms
```

If I understand the socket.io doco correctly it injects placeholders and sends the binary in another request. So this kinda looks ok to me.

I have a HTML/Javascript test client I'm using to test the query and it's original request looked like this:

```
socket.emit('listProjects', function (data) {
        writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">Ack: ' + data + '</span>');
    });
```

Producing the log in the console shows this:

```
[Log] engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "61-0[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]]" +6ms (socket.io.js, line 1)
[Log] socket.io-parser decoded 61-0[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]] as {"type":6,"attachments":1,"nsp":"/","id":0,"data":[null,[{"id":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0},"name":"Test project"}]]} +6ms (socket.io.js, line 1)
[Log] engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "ArrayBuffer" +1ms (socket.io.js, line 1)
[Log] socket.io-client:socket calling ack 0 with [null,[{"id":{},"name":"Test project"}]] +0ms (socket.io.js, line 1)
[Log] Data: null (Tester.html, line 55)
```

Basically the ack argument to the `emit` is coming back with a null. I would have thought at the very least it would be set to the data that is showing in the console. Even if it had a null `id` value.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: you are not showing the code so I am not sure but... shouldn't you rather write `socket.on('listProjects', function (data) ...` etc ? Just guessing ;)

Comment: Thanks but no. `on(` is for responding to incoming events. I wanted to send an event and received an immediate synchronous respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this was my bad. On the server I'm using Promises and responding with standard `function(err, data)` calls. So my emit should have been:

```
socket.emit('listProjects', function (err, data) {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">Ack: ' + data + '</span>');
});
```